# CPAN installation proble, HTTP::Message on CentOS

Tags: centos, cpan

I have a perl script that needs a long list of prerequisites. While installing these, I am not getting past the installation of HTTP::Message

When I run cpan HTTP::Message from the command line as root, I get the following output:

> cpan HTTP::Message
>
> Reading '/root/.cpan/Metadata'
>
> Database was generated on Mon, 27 Apr 2015 12:53:26 GMT
>
> Running install for module 'HTTP::Message'
>
> Running make for G/GA/GAAS/HTTP-Message-6.06.tar.gz
>
> Checksum for
>   /root/.cpan/sources/authors/id/G/GA/GAAS/HTTP-Message-6.06.tar.gz  ok
>
> CPAN.pm: Building G/GA/GAAS/HTTP-Message-6.06.tar.gz
>
> Checking if your kit is complete...
>
> Looks good
>
> Warning: prerequisite Encode::Locale 1 not found.
>
> Warning: prerequisite HTTP::Date 6 not found.
>
> Warning: prerequisite IO::HTML 0 not found.
>
> Warning: prerequisite LWP::MediaTypes 6 not found.
>
> Warning: prerequisite URI 1.10 not found.
>
> Writing Makefile for HTTP::Message

However, I have run cpan individually for all of those prerequisites (as root), and the install succeeded.

What am I missing here?

I am running CentOS Linux release 7.1.1503 (Core)

Comment: What's wrong with just doing `yum install perl-HTTP-Message`? Why are you trying to use CPAN? You should avoid using CPAN when the perl modules are already packaged.

Comment: Thanks @Michael, that worked!! If you add your advice (use YUM rather than CPAN where possible) as an answer, I'll mark that as the resolution to my problem :-)

Comment: Are you sure you setup CPAN to auto-install dependencies? It's part of that wizard that launches the first time you run it. From perl monks, you can rerun the wizard with the following two part command: "rm /etc/perl/CPAN/Config.pm ; perl -MCPAN -e shell"

I usually use 100% default values.

Comment: @SomeLinuxNerd, I have that option enabled, CPAN was just not installing that module, its compilation failed saying that the dependencies are not there (even though they are!!). Installing the Yum package worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What's wrong with just doing `yum install perl-HTTP-Message`? Why are you trying to use CPAN? You should avoid using CPAN when the perl modules are already packaged.